# The menu that shows up when a new mesh is added disappears when I click on it

Tags: interface

I am not able to access the menu when we add a new mesh. It disappears when I click on it. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use all caps in your titles - instead make them descriptive to help people understand what your question is about just by looking at it.

Comment: Did you try pressing F6 after creating an object?

Answer (score 2):

Adjust Last Operation panel can be used just after some operation is performed. It does not disappear if you click on it, however it will disappear when you click somewhere else.

It is possible to bring it back by going to Edit-> Adjust Last Operation or with <kbd>F9</kbd>, however this is only until you perform some other operation. When you do, it becomes the new last performed operation, the previous operation then becomes completely finished and you cannot change its parameters any more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as mentioned. <kbd>F9</kbd> as mentioned in another anwser did also not work for me. I solved it by resetting to defaults.

*File → Defaults → Load Factory Settings*

I guess this problem happened using unstable builds and developers changed something, which did not work well with my configuration.

Keep in mind that doing this will reset all your Blender changes to defaults.