# Different options in Blender 2.8 when selecting Loop Cut via the toolbar or the shortcut (CTRL+R)

Tags: shortcut

I noticed that when you select the Loop Cut via the toolbar on the left side you cannot adjust the number of cuts via the mouse wheel. If you scroll the mouse wheel, the camera zooms in and out. It is different if you select the loopcut with the key combination CTRL+R. Then you can set the number of cuts with the mouse wheel as usual. Can anyone tell me how to set the number of cuts when selecting the Loop Cut via the toolbar? Why is the behaviour different here at all? And is it the same with other commands? That would mean that a command/tool behaves fundamentally different if you select it via the key combination or the toolbar.

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem logical, anyway you must have seen that you can set the number in the operator box

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I am just starting to learn Blender and I came across this strange behaviour right at the beginning. It's confusing, of course.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 2.8 yet but I think you should use the shortcuts as soon as possible, rather than the left panel ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little pop-up menu, where you can adjust the parameters.
The tool works the same, you only don't control it through shortcuts.

It's an alternative for those who don't like using shortcuts :). (like me)

[image]

Comment: How do you open the popup?

Comment: Hello :). It should be visible by default. If not, this thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145719/