# Missing menu in xyz math extra objects

Tags: add-on

I am using version 2.9 I have looked at several videos and posts, but do not see this problem.
I lose the menu when using the xyz math functions.
see: https://youtu.be/t_ht2uAW9Lg
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is usually better, and in this way in particular, to provide 2 screenshots of the problem outlined in question (before and after) without requiring others to watch the video just to understand what's the question is about. See general solution on the question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7850/1245, also https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145719/1245. That menu is there only after performing adjacent operator

Comment: Here is the answer. Use the F9 key. If you wish you can see the details here: https://youtu.be/cqcHrFmfQLg?t=41

Comment: Mr. Zak, yes, you answer basically gave me the information I needed.

Comment: Mr. Zak, also thanks for the quick reply.